# Perform inner join filtering defined values

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following two tables. What I'm trying to achieve is a search that returns ranked results, when a match is found in `A1.pagetitle`, `A1.content` or `A2.value` - in that order.

But I only need to include results from the second table where the `tmplvarid` matches specific values (in this case, 15 or 17).

```
 mod_site_content (A1)
 +----+-----------+--------------+
 | id | pagetitle | content      |
 +----+-----------+--------------+
 | 1  | home      | <p> ... </p> |
 | 2  | project 1 | <p> ... </p> |
 | 3  | comment 1 | <p> ... </p> |
 | 4  | project 2 | <p> ... </p> |
 | 5  | project 3 | <p> ... </p> |
 | 6  | comment 2 | <p> ... </p> |
 | etc ...                       |
 +----+-----------+--------------+

 mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues (A2)
 +----+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
 | id | tmplvarid | contentid | value           |
 +----+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
 | 1  | 2         | 1         | [{"key":"val"}] |
 | 2  | 2         | 2         | [{"key":"val"}] |
 | 3  | 5         | 1         | [{"key":"val"}] |
 | 4  | 5         | 5         | [{"key":"val"}] |
 | 5  | 15        | 4         | [{"key":"val"}] |
 | 6  | 15        | 5         | [{"key":"val"}] |
 | etc ...                                      |
 +----+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

I think I'm almost there - currently I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
    CASE
        WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE ? THEN 1
        WHEN A1.content LIKE ? THEN 2
        WHEN A2.value LIKE ? THEN 3
    END AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1
INNER JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
    ON A1.id = A2.contentid
WHERE pagetitle LIKE ?
    OR content LIKE ?
    OR value LIKE ?
ORDER BY rank
```

But this includes *all* corresponding `contentid`s - I can't for the life of me figure out how to incorporate a condition that only includes certain ones.

Comment: which specific ones do you want to include? just the first? theres multiple so you need to clarify

Comment: I only want to include any/all entries from the second table with a `tmplvarid` of 15 or 17.

Comment: i just edited my query... it will join the table and filter appropriately.. I added a demo for you to look at as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you join filter the results on the join column like so

**FOR RETURNING ROWS WHEN IN BOTH TABLES:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
    CASE
        WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE ? THEN 1
        WHEN A1.content LIKE ? THEN 2
        WHEN A2.value LIKE ? THEN 3
    END AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1
INNER JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
    ON A1.id = A2.contentid
    AND A2.tmplvarid IN(15,17)
WHERE (pagetitle LIKE ?
    OR content LIKE ?
    OR value LIKE ?)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b8d4/1)

---

**FOR RETURNING ROWS FROM mod_site_content AND ANY MATCHING FROM mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
    CASE
        WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE ? THEN 1
        WHEN A1.content LIKE ? THEN 2
        WHEN A2.value LIKE ? THEN 3
    END AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1
LEFT JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
    ON A1.id = A2.contentid
    AND A2.tmplvarid IN(15,17)
WHERE (pagetitle LIKE ?
    OR content LIKE ?
    OR value LIKE ?)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b8d4/2)

Comment: This looks very promising - out of interest, will it still include results when nothing is found in `mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`?

Comment: @verism it wont if its an INNER JOIN ... it will if its a LEFT JOIN.. I just edited it to be a LEFT JOIN incase you want it to include results in the mod_site_content when there isn't matches in mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues

Comment: sqlfiddle is taking a while to load, so I'm unable to check, but it appears to be exactly right on my data. Thanks very much.

Comment: the output is all of the rows in the first table with null values for anything not matching the join conditions in the other table. glad I could help! good luck with your programming adventures!

Answer (score 1):

just add your condition at the end!

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
    CASE
        WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE ? THEN 1
        WHEN A1.content LIKE ? THEN 2
        WHEN A2.value LIKE ? THEN 3
    END AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1
INNER JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
    ON A1.id = A2.contentid
WHERE (pagetitle LIKE ?
    OR content LIKE ?
    OR value LIKE ?)
    AND A2.contentid in (15,17)
```

ORDER BY rank

Comment: I'd already tried that - it doesn't work. (Edit: just noticed the parentheses). This returns an empty array, even for valid search queries.

Comment: @verism as i understand in last condition must by tmplvarid, not contentid

Comment: Ah, that's much better. Does this still include results when nothing is found in `mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` ?

Comment: @verism to include results, when nothing is found in `mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` you must use LEFT JOIN, if use INNER JOIN - then no.